# What is StubRoutines::jbyte_disjoint_arraycopy

Tags: java, jvm, jmh

I'm measuring some single-threaded method invocation (written in Scala) and wanted to analyze the benchmark. Here is how it looks like (implementation details omitted)

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
class TheBenchmarks {

    var data: Array[Byte] = _
    @Param(Array("1024", "2048", "4096", "8192"))
    var chunkSize: Int = _

    @Setup
    def setup(): Unit = {
        data = //get the data
    }

    @Benchmark
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
    @BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.AverageTime))
    def takeFirstAvroRecord(bh: Blackhole): Unit = {
      val fr = //do computation with data and chunk size
      bh.consume(fr)
    }

}
```

Okay, I got some result and wanted to understand it, but the output of the  `-prof perfasm` is a bit unclear to me. First of all:

```
....[Hottest Regions]...............................................................................
 44.20%   40.50%        runtime stub  StubRoutines::jbyte_disjoint_arraycopy (205 bytes) 
  6.78%    1.62%         C2, level 4  cats.data.IndexedStateT$$Lambda$21::apply, version 1242 (967 bytes) 
  4.39%    0.79%         C2, level 4  my.pack.age.Mclass::cut0, version 1323 (299 bytes)
```

and

```
....[Hottest Methods (after inlining)]..............................................................
 44.20%   40.50%        runtime stub  StubRoutines::jbyte_disjoint_arraycopy 
  8.40%    3.93%         C2, level 4  cats.data.IndexedStateT$$Lambda$21::apply, version 1242 
  5.76%    2.67%         C2, level 4  my.pack.age.Mclass::cut0, version 1323
```

I found some about `jbyte_disjoint_arraycopy`. It is declared as follows [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/c1374141598c/src/cpu/x86/vm/stubGenerator_x86_64.cpp#l2815) as follows.

```
StubRoutines::_jbyte_disjoint_arraycopy  = generate_disjoint_byte_copy(false, &entry,
                                                                           "jbyte_disjoint_arraycopy");
```

Judging by the source of the `generate_disjoint_byte_copy` method it looks like an assembly code generation thing... I could guess that it is some intrinsic array copy for `x86`...

***Question:*** Can you please give some explanation about the `StubRoutines` and what may cause it to be the hottest region?

Comment: I see two different questions here: 1) What is stub routine is and how does it work. 2) What is the problem with Hotspot disassembler. Not sure which one to answer - please ask one question per post.

Comment: @apangin Irrelevant part removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You guessed right. `<type>_disjoint_arraycopy` stubs are functions generated in run time specifically for speeding up `System.arraycopy` calls.

When JVM starts, it produces optimized machine code for certain routines using currently available [CPU features](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/c1374141598c/src/cpu/x86/vm/vm_version_x86.cpp#l402). E.g. if CPU supports AVX2, generated `arraycopy` stubs will [make use of AVX2 instructions](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/c1374141598c/src/cpu/x86/vm/stubGenerator_x86_64.cpp#l1297).

`System.arraycopy` is HotSpot intrinsic method. When compiled by C2, an invocation of `System.arraycopy` performs neccessary checks and then calls one of the generated `arraycopy` stub routines.

If `StubRoutines::jbyte_disjoint_arraycopy` is the hottest region, it basically means that your benchmark spends most of the time inside `System.arraycopy` dealing with `byte[]` arrays. You may try [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) to see where this `arraycopy` is called from.

Comment: Can you get some idea about how this feature check is performed? I went through the `generate_disjoint_byte_copy` and did not notice any AVX2 related instructions/registers used. Maybe its in some another place...?

Comment: @St.Antario Updated the answer with the links to `VM_Version::get_processor_features()` and AVX2 usages.

Comment: Now I see. Thanks much.